# scanf and printf not executed in order

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I'm writing a simple code to acquire an input from the user. Here's my code:

```
int main() {

    char *start = NULL;
    char *end = NULL;
    char in, out, shift;

    while (strcmp(start, "acc") != 0) {
        printf("before start");
        scanf("%ms ", &start);

        if(strcmp(start, "acc") != 0) {
            printf("in if");
            scanf("%c %c %c %ms", &in, &out, &shift, &end);
            printf("%s", start);
            printf("%c", in);
            printf("%c", out);
            printf("%c", shift);
            printf("%s", end);
        }
    }
}
```

The input is always something like this:

```
string char char char string
```

with the first and last string of arbitrary length (that's why I'm using `%ms`)

The code works fine and does what it has to do, the only problem is that I want to check if my `start` string is equal to `acc`, if so, skip those lines of code.

When I insert `acc` into my `scanf("%ms ", &start);` and I press enter, my code still waits for all the other inputs to be inserted, once they are all inserted it check all the conditions, makes all the prints and then it ends.

What is the problem?

Comment: You have a whole bunch of stuff causing undefined behaviors. Such as `strcmp` with an uninitialized pointer, reading into that pointer and so on.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Didn't think about that. The problem is that i'm using the strcmp over a pointer that could point to random things, am i right?

Comment: That's one problem. You have more, so let's wait for someone less lazy than myself to write a nice answer listing all :)

Comment: I've tried to remove the space after scanf("%ms") and added it into the other scanf, now it works

Comment: But i still would like to know the problems of my code!

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio the problem in your initial code is that you use `strcmp` with the non initialized pointer `start`. This is _undefined behaviour_ (google that term). _undefined behaviour_ goes from "apparently working fine" to "program behaves very strangely".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the uninitialized pointer `start`, a do/while loop would be better suited to allow input to that variable before testing it with `strcmp`.
I am not sure if `%ms` allocates a new buffer with each call. Since the buffer does not need to be initialized, I suspect it allocates a new buffer. To avoid memory leaks, `free` the buffers before they are needed and after they are no longer needed.
The space after `%ms` will consume all trailing whitespace. To terminate the scan is is necessary to input some non-whitespace. Move that trailing space to the next `scanf` before the first `%c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char *start = NULL;
    char *end = NULL;
    char in, out, shift;

    do {
        if ( start) {
            free ( start);
            start = NULL;
        }
        printf("before start: ");
        fflush ( stdout);
        scanf("%ms", &start);

        if(strcmp(start, "acc") != 0) {
            if ( end) {
                free ( end);
                end = NULL;
            }
            printf("in if: ");
            fflush ( stdout);
            scanf(" %c %c %c %ms", &in, &out, &shift, &end);
            printf("%s", start);
            printf("%c", in);
            printf("%c", out);
            printf("%c", shift);
            printf("%s", end);
        }
    } while ( strcmp(start, "acc") != 0);

    if ( start) {
        free ( start);
        start = NULL;
    }
    if ( end) {
        free ( end);
        end = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're right, i forgot about de-allocate memory. I've been using Java for a while and i got used to garbage collector, my bad

Comment: Better as in "not Undefined Behavior (UB)?